Can't get the correct output when connecting C++ and SQL
Here are the instructions for the PL/SQL procedures, as well as the C++ function, but I can't seem to get it right.

customer_order (customerID IN number, orderID IN OUT number)

This procedure receives two values as customer ID and Order ID and confirms if this given order belongs to this given customer in the orders table. If the order ID belongs to this customer ID, the procedure passes the order ID to the caller. Otherwise, it passes 0 to the caller.
void cancelOrder(Connection* conn, int orderId, int customerId);

This function first calls the customer_order stored procedure to confirm the entered order ID belongs to the customer. If the value of the second parameter of the customer_order procedure is a non-zero value, the order ID belongs to the customer. If the value of the second parameter of the customer_order procedure is zero, display the following message:
“Order does not belong to the customer.”
If the order ID belongs to the customer, then call the cancel_order procedure to the order with the order ID passed to this function.

If the value passed by the second parameter of the cancel_order is 1, display:
“The order has been already canceled.”

If the value passed by the second parameter of the cancel_order is 2, display:
“The order is shipped and cannot be cancelled.”

If the value passed by the second parameter of the cancel_order is 3, display:
“The order is cancelled successfully.”



Here is my code:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE customer_order (
    customerID IN NUMBER,
    orderID IN OUT NUMBER
) AS
    temp_order_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT order_id INTO temp_order_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE customer_id = customerID AND order_id = orderID;

    orderID := temp_order_id;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        orderID := 0;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: Multiple orders found for the customer.');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An unexpected error occurred: ' || SQLERRM);
END;

C++:
void cancelOrder(Connection* conn, int orderId, int customerId) {
    try {
        Statement* stmt = nullptr;
        int cancelStatus = 0;

        stmt = conn->createStatement("BEGIN customer_order(:1, :2); END;");
        stmt->setInt(1, customerId);         
        stmt->setInt(2, orderId);           
        stmt->registerOutParam(2, Type::OCCIINT); 
        stmt->executeUpdate();

        int validatedOrderId = stmt->getInt(2); 

        if (validatedOrderId == 0) {
            cout << "Order does not belong to the customer." << endl;
            conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
            return; 
        }
        stmt->setSQL("BEGIN cancel_order(:1, :2); END;");
        stmt->setInt(1, validatedOrderId);   
        stmt->registerOutParam(2, Type::OCCIINT); 
        stmt->executeUpdate();
        cancelStatus = stmt->getInt(2); 

        switch (cancelStatus) {
        case 1:
            cout << "The order has been already canceled." << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "The order is shipped and cannot be canceled." << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "The order is canceled successfully." << endl;
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "The order does not exist." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Unknown cancel status." << endl;
            break;
        }

        conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    }
    catch (SQLException& sqlExcp) {
        cout << "Error: Unable to cancel the order." << endl;
        cout << sqlExcp.getErrorCode() << ": " << sqlExcp.getMessage() << endl;
    }
}

FYI, this is the cancel_order procedure below. I don't think I have any issues for this. It's just that I can't figure out how to confirm the order ID to belong to a customer.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cancel_order (
    orderID IN NUMBER,
    cancelStatus OUT NUMBER
) AS
    orderStatus VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    SELECT status INTO orderStatus
    FROM orders
    WHERE order_id = orderID;

    CASE
        WHEN orderStatus = 'Canceled' THEN
            cancelStatus := 1;
        WHEN orderStatus = 'Shipped' THEN
            cancelStatus := 2;
        ELSE
            UPDATE orders
            SET status = 'Canceled'
            
            WHERE order_id = orderID;
            cancelStatus := 3;
    END CASE;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        cancelStatus := 0;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An unexpected error occurred: ' || SQLERRM);
END;


Your SQL is not T-SQL; are you sure you're using SQL Server? PL/SQL is used by Oracle.

PL/SQL is Oracle, not Microsoft SQL Server. Corrected your tag.

Why is your C++ code wrapping the stored procedure calls inside of Statements instead of just invoking the stored procedures directly?

Don't use DBMS_OUTPUT to print to the console - the C++ program will not see the console output. Instead, let the exception be raised and catch it in C++ and print the appropriate output when you catch the exceptions.
